# Kivy: How to change the attribute's value like text of label from current screen in another screen

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I tried to change the text of another screen from current screen. But it didn't work

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder


Builder.load_string("""
<Input_Screen>:
    input: input
    BoxLayout:
        orientation : "vertical"
        TextInput:
            id: input
            text: "Changed"
        Button:
            text: "Enter"
            on_press : root.clicked()
            
<Display_Screen>:
    nice: nice
    BoxLayout:
        orientation : "vertical"
        Label:
            id: nice
            text: "NotChanged"
    

""")


class Input_Screen(Screen):
    input = ObjectProperty(None)
    def clicked(self):
        Display_Screen().change()

class Display_Screen(Screen):
    nice = ObjectProperty(None)
    def change(self):
        print(self.nice.text) #Checking the Current text of The Label
        print(Input_Screen().input.text) #Checking What do we want to change
        self.nice.text = Input_Screen().input.text
        print(self.nice.text) #Checking if it has change or not
        MyApp().sm.current = "Ds" #Changing Screen to Display_Screen
        print(self.nice.text) #Checking if it has change or not


class MyApp(App):
    sm = ScreenManager()
    def build(self):
        self.sm.add_widget(Input_Screen(name="Is"))
        self.sm.add_widget(Display_Screen(name="Ds"))
        return self.sm

MyApp().run()
```

What I get in My console:

```
NotChanged #Checked the Current text of The Label
Changed #Checked What do we want to change
Changed #Checked if it has change or not
Changed #Checked if it has change or not
```

It says that my Label's text has been changed but when it goes to the next screen it hasn't been changed.

[Display_Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUPVy.png)

Anyone knows whats the problem? Help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use a construction like `ClassName()`, you are creating a new instance of `ClassName`. You are doing this in your `change()` method and in your `clicked()` method. Whenever you do that, you are referencing that new instance, and not the instance that is in your GUI.

To fix that, change:

```
def clicked(self):
    Display_Screen().change()
```

to:

```
def clicked(self):
    self.manager.get_screen('Ds').change()
```

and in your `change()` method, replace:

```
Input_Screen()
```

with:

```
self.manager.get_screen('Is')
```

and replace"

```
MyApp()
```

with:

```
App.get_running_app()
```